# Kotlin Flow: Handling state using SharedFlow and StateFlow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow, kotlin-sharedflow

I have this use case where response from data source are guaranteed to be consume and not missed after configuration change, but also do not repeat it when already consume.

`StateFlow` seems to be the best candidate as it holds last emitted value but can be problematic on a following scenario:

1. Data source response with the same error on each request (maybe due to having no data in local cache or network issue.)

As `StateFlow` does not emit the same value, this can be problematic where after a new request to data source, an error state (can be dialog) will not show again in the UI if the previous state is also error.

Using `SharedFlow` with configured `replay`

```
MutableSharedFlow<T>(replay = 1, onBufferOverflow = BufferOverflow.DROP_OLDEST)
```

This will behave like a `LiveData` with `repeatOnLifecycle`, but has its own issue on the following scenario.

Let say we have these states

```
sealed class AssetState {
    data class FetchAssetLoading(val assetList: List<AssetMinDataDomain>?) : AssetState()
    data class FetchAssetSuccess(val assetList: List<AssetMinDataDomain>) : AssetState()
    data class FetchAssetFailed(val msg: String, val assetList: List<AssetMinDataDomain>?) : AssetState()
}
```

Inside `onCreate` or `onViewCreated`

```
// Initial fetch
fetchData(param1, param2)

// Collecting the result of fetch data 
with(viewModel) {
   viewLifecycleOwner.collectShared(assetState, ::onAssetStateChanged)
}
```

Extension function

```
inline fun <T : Any, L : SharedFlow<T>> LifecycleOwner.collectShared(
    sharedFlow: L,
    crossinline function: (T) -> Unit,
    lifecycleState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(lifecycleState) {
            sharedFlow.collect { t -> function(t) }
        }
    }
}
```

When a configuration change happens, the `fetchData(param1, param2)` will be triggered and its result will be collected when the `LifeCycle` at least reached `STARTED` but since we also use `repeatOnLifecycle` there will be two emission of data. One as a result of request `fetchData` which is more updated and one as the result of `repeatOnLifecycle` which can be outdated. The only solution I see as of the moment is to add a empty state or no state then manually set it after receiving success state of failed state in the UI but seems not the best solution and too repetitive. Is there a better way to satisfy the above requirements? Thanks

P.S

If I remove `repeat = 1` in `SharedFlow` it will solve the issue, however if the activity went `onStop` e.g. the user press home button while fetching data then went back to the app causing `onStart` and `onResume` to trigger then we will lose that event and its result.

Comment: Do you mean if the state was responded to before a configuration change, you want it to be ignored after the configuration change? What you're describing sounds like events, not state, so StateFlow definitely would not be appropriate. StateFlow is for "state", which implies collectors only care about current status.

Comment: It seems you should initiate fetching of data from the ViewModel, so it will happen only once no matter how many times the STARTED state is reached for the same screen of your app.

Comment: @Tenfour04, putting it inside ViewModel's init is actually my first instinct. However, the Activity or Fragment is sometimes responsible for triggering it example via button and needs to receive parameter as its input for queries so I cannot do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, to perform single event using flows is using Channel and turn it to regular cold flow like this

ViewModel

```
private val _assetState = Channel<AssetState>()

val assetState = _assetState.receiveAsFlow()
```

To emit use `send`

```
// Some method 
_assetState.send(AssetState.FetchLoading())
```

Collecting the result of fetch data

```
with(viewModel) {
   viewLifecycleOwner.collectFlow(assetState, ::onAssetStateChanged)
}
```

Update extension function

```
inline fun <T : Any, L : Flow<T>> LifecycleOwner.collectFlow(
    flow: L,
    crossinline function: (T) -> Unit,
    lifecycleState: Lifecycle.State = Lifecycle.State.STARTED
) {
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        repeatOnLifecycle(lifecycleState) {
            flow.collect { t -> function(t) }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that there is a subtle catch on using this approach where you can still missed an event if Channel sent the event but the consumer just in time suddenly went background based on the set LifeCycle.

Reference: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodel-one-off-event-antipatterns-16a1da869b95